# How to make my menu on the same horizontal line?

Tags: css, reactjs

I was building the menu in template webiste.

What should i do to make my menu on the same horizontal line?

What i want is

> LOGO    01xxxx   02xxxxx  03xxxxx  04xxxx

not

> LOGO
>
> 01xxxx  02xxxx  03xxxx  04xxxx....

My website show in localhost 3000:
[image]

My header.js

```
   import React from 'react';
   import image from './images/0.png'
   import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
   import { faHome } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
   import './Header.css'

   const Header = () =>{
      return(
        <div>
         <nav>
            <div>
               <div>

                <div>
                        <a href="#home">
                        <img src={image} alt="logo"/>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div className="container">
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a  href="#01文字文字">01文字文字</a></li>
                            <li><a  href="#02文字文字">02文字文字</a></li>
                            <li><a  href="#03文字文字">03文字文字</a></li>
                            <li><a  href="#04文字文字">04文字文字</a></li>
                            <li><a  href="#Test文字文字">Test文字文字</a></li>
                            <li><a  href="#回首頁"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHome} />回首頁</a></li>
                         </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    </div>
);
}

export default Header
```

My Header.css:

```
ul {
padding-left: 0;
list-style-type: none;
}
li {
 float: left;
 padding-left: 10px;
}
  li:first-child {
 padding-left: 0;
}
```

My app.js:

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
 import Center from './Components/Center';
 import Header from './Components/Header';

 class App extends Component {
   render() {
return (
  <div>
      <Header/>
      <Center/>
  </div>
   );
 }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: `list-style-type: none` to make the bullets disappear...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please replace your code with this

```
   <nav>
          <div class="flex-container">
            <div>
              <a href="#home">
                <img src={image} alt="logo" />
              </a>
            </div>

            <div className="container">
              <div>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#01文字文字">01文字文字</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#02文字文字">02文字文字</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#03文字文字">03文字文字</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#04文字文字">04文字文字</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#Test文字文字">Test文字文字</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#回首頁">
                      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHome} />
                      回首頁
                    </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
```

Add CSS

```
.flex-container{
    display: flex;
}

ul{
    display: flex;
}
li{
    margin-right: 35px;
    list-style: none;
}
a{

text-decoration:none
}
```

Comment: Would you read the question again?How to make <li> and LOGO on the same horizontal line?

Comment: ohhh sorryy, Its simple for that give display:flex for the nav tag

Comment: @Jacky ,  I have updated the answer , This will work

Comment: One little thing .... How to make the word's underline disappear without delete <a href>?

Comment: Inside the <a> tag css , just give , text-decoration:none

Comment: OK...Thanks for answer!

Answer (score 0):

You need to give `display` inline to `li` tag.

```css
.container li{
   display: inline;
   width: 200px;
   height: 50px;
   border: 2px #ccc solid;
   margin-right: 10px;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   list-style: none;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go for:

```
ul {
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
li {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
li:first-child {
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

Thanks to that it will be horizontal and you will get rid of that dot on the left of each list item + there will be no padding which each unordered list has by default.

Answer (score 0):

Can you have the DOM structure slight changed to achieve the same without any further changes.

```html
<div>
  <nav>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div className="container">
          <div>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#home">
                  <img src={image} alt="logo"/>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#01文字文字">01文字文字</a></li>
              <li><a href="#02文字文字">02文字文字</a></li>
              <li><a href="#03文字文字">03文字文字</a></li>
              <li><a href="#04文字文字">04文字文字</a></li>
              <li><a href="#Test文字文字">Test文字文字</a></li>
              <li>
                <a href="#回首頁">
                  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHome} />回首頁</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!